# creating a new dataframe from value.counts()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df_1` with a column `year` which denotes when the year a crime occurred. So for example, df_1 is something like this:

```
   location    description   Weapon   Year
0  Howard Ave   Auto theft   Knife    2017
1  Craig Drive  Burglary     Gun      2014
2  King Ave     Assault      Hands    2017
```

I need to create a dataframe that has the number of crime occurrences by year from 2012-2017.

```
crime_year = pd.DataFrame(df_1.year.value_counts(), columns=["Year", "AggregateCrime"])
crime_yearindex = crime_year.sort_index(axis = 0, ascending=True)
crime_yearindex
```

When I print `crime_yearindex`, I just get the column headers and not the data itself. What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: The second thing you did wrong, was not providing enough context to answer this. Try to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showcasing your problem including the creatiion of your dataframe with some demodata . Edit your questions and provide it as code example. Use the button **{}** after marking all your code to format is as code block.

Comment: I edited to provide more context. Please let me know if its framed better now.

Comment: a MVCE is a Minimal Verifyable Complete Example. Meaning: I copy your code into my IDE, execute it, see the error. Your code would need to have some of your data, and a way to construct the `df_1` from it so we can see where your code goes wrong.

Comment: OK I added a sample dataframe as an example.

Answer (score 8):

When you are doing `value_counts`, it will return a series, so I am adding `.reset_index().values` after  `value_counts`, to make index also become the value

```
crime_year = pd.DataFrame(df.Year.value_counts().reset_index().values, columns=["Year", "AggregateCrime"])
crime_yearindex = crime_year.sort_index(axis = 0, ascending=True)
crime_yearindex
Out[1225]: 
   Year  AggregateCrime
0  2017               2
1  2014               1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `.groupby()` function to get yearly counts of crime occurances.

So in this case `df_1.groupby(by="Year").count()` would get you the crime count of every year

After that you could use `.loc` to select specific years